# How do I link Intel MKL and libdl with gold linker?

Tags: c, centos, glibc, intel-mkl, gold-linker

I'm having a problem linking Intel MKL and libdl using the gold linker on CentOS:

When I run this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

MKL_INC=$MKL_INSTALL_DIR/include
MKL_LIB=$MKL_INSTALL_DIR/lib

. /opt/rh/devtoolset-6/enable

cat > t.c << end_mkltest

#include <dlfcn.h>
#include "mkl_service.h"

int main() {
    dlerror();              /* use libdl */
    mkl_set_num_threads(1); /* use mkl   */
}

end_mkltest

gcc -I$MKL_INC -c t.c -o t.o
gcc -L$MKL_LIB -fuse-ld=gold t.o -lmkl_rt -ldl
```

I get:

```
libmkl_rt.so: error: undefined reference to 'calloc'
libmkl_rt.so: error: undefined reference to 'realloc'
libmkl_rt.so: error: undefined reference to 'malloc'
libmkl_rt.so: error: undefined reference to 'free'
```

We're using:

```
CentOS 7.3
devtoolset-6
mkl-2017.2.174.tar.bz2
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.  Can you post the linker command shown by this command?

```
gcc -v -L$MKL_LIB -fuse-ld=gold t.o -lmkl_rt -ldl
```

(Sorry, can't post this as a comment due to lack of reputation.)